# Why does x * x is computed wrong?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I am trying find the `nth` number in the array with first element `3` and next elements built after the following rule: `v[i] = (v[i - 1] * v[i - 1] / (i + 2) + v[i - 1] * i + i + 1) % 666013`. Where `v` is the array. I think my code is working, but I have the next problem. For `n = 7` first `y = 600198`, and at the next step `y = 3755353636`, but I expected `y` at that step to be `360237639204`. Why does that happen? I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7 ultimate x64.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input;
    if ((input = fopen("C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication2\\hex.in", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening hex.in\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *output;
    if ((output = fopen("hex.out", "w+")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening hex.out\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int n;
    fscanf_s(input, "%d", &n);
    int i = 1;
    unsigned long x = 3;
    unsigned long y = 8;
    bool found = false;
    while(!found)
    {
        if (i == n)
        {
            found = true;
            fprintf(output, "%d", x);
        }
        i++;
        x = y;
        y = x * x;//for i = 7 I expect y to be 360237639204 after this step
        y /= (i + 2);
        y += x * i;
        y += i + 1;
        y %= 666013;
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `unsigned long long`, 32 bits wont hold that value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio C++ compiler still have `long` (and `unsigned long` too of course) as a 32-bit datatype. Use `long long` if you want a (at least) 64-bit integer datatype.

Answer (score 2):

You have integer overflow, try to use 64-bit variable.

`unsigned long` can accept number up to `2^32-1` which is less than you have expected and that's why you have overflow.

Use 64-bit variable instead:

```
unsigned long long x = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

A 32-bit integer can represent 2^32-1 (around 4 billion) values. The result you desire is around 360 billion. So you can roughly imagine it as having wrapped around 360 / 4 = 90 times and was left with a remainder of around 3 billion, the result you're actually seeing.

Use a 64-bit integer instead, as others have stated.

```
unsigned long long x = 3;
unsigned long long y = 8;
```